# Symfony 1.4: not bringing info from DB or rendering the template

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a DB that has the **label** table with info in it. I created a module in the admin with the only function of **listing** the information of that table **label** which fields are: **id, text** (for ex: 1 Sony, 2 Warner, etc.)

Nevertheless: When I enter to the module -in the browser- I just see the **title** that I wrote in the **generator.yml**, but not the **display** of the fields of the **list** (this is: from the database). I re-checked in **databases.yml** that the info there is OK. I can enter to the DB and see the information.

Here are some relevant files:

**generator.yml**:

```
generator:
  class: sfPropelGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           Label
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              Label
    plural:                Labels
    route_prefix:          label
    with_propel_route:     1
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

  config:
    actions: ~
    fields:  ~
    list:
      title: it's working!!
      fields:
      display:  [id, text]   
    filter:  ~
    form:    ~   
    edit:    ~  
    new:     ~
```

**NOTE:** only appears **it's working!!** when I do: *page.com/label*. Not the info of the DB. I already played with the capital letters  in the **param** of the **generator.yml**. Also, deleted the cache every time, after the changes and checked the indentation -two spaces, no tabs-

In the folder **/template** I don't have any template. In **/actions** I have:

**actions.class.php*:*

```
class labelActions extends sfActions 
{
 /**
  * Executes index action
  *
  * @param sfRequest $request A request object
  */
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
   //$this->forward('default', 'module');
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** just commented a line. As says the instructions when you create a new module, to eliminate the default **Symfony** screen.

The **routing.yml** which is in the **config** folder of the father of all the modules:

**routing.yml**:

```
...
label:
  class: sfPropelRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                Label
    module:               label
    prefix_path:          /label
    column:               id
    with_wildcard_routes: true  
 ...
```

**NOTE:** played with the capital letters too, ex: label, Label, etc. Cleaned cache every time.

Comment: Your `actions.class.php` is strange... If you use a generator you will have an actions like this one: http://svn.jobeet.org/trunk/apps/backend/modules/category/actions/actions.class.php with `class labelActions extends autoLabelActions`

Comment: I see: thank you. I found my mistake: I generate the module and after that the module-admin. If I generate the admin module alone, everything works fine (php symfony propel:generate-admin cms --module=label Label  **note**: Label is the table) with that I see the action.class as you say. Thank you again. **PD: if you put the answer I will accept it!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `actions.class.php` is strange...

If you use a generator you must have an actions like that:

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/labelGeneratorConfiguration.class.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/labelGeneratorHelper.class.php';

/**
 * label actions.
 *
 * @package    domain
 * @subpackage label
 * @author     Your name here
 * @version    SVN: $Id: actions.class.php 12474 2008-10-31 10:41:27Z fabien $
 */
class labelActions extends autoLabelActions
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you!. Please read the comments of the questions for a complete solution.